# NoClassDefFound Error in Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am not able to mock the class which is in external libraries in IntelliJIdea. Its giving me an error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/adobe/cq/mcm/salesforce/SalesforceClient
    at com.ig.igwebcms.services.test.SalesforceLeadSearch1Test.testGetSalesforceClientObject(SalesforceLeadSearch1Test.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Below is my code :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SalesforceLeadSearch1Test  {
    @Test
    public void testGetSalesforceClientObject() throws Exception {
        SalesforceClient client = mock(SalesforceClient.class);
        Map configProps=mock(Map.class);
    }
}
```

I have checked, dependency is available in maven' POM as well. Same exception is coming for all classes in external libraries when try to mock them. & Mock for map class doesn't give this error.

Comment: I don't know of any limitation or error in Mockito that would cause a NoClassDefFoundError. It is very likely an issue with your runtime classpath instead.

Comment: That was because i was selecting wrong junit version in wizard, It should be JUnit4

Answer (score 0):

Mockito can't mock everything. In fact in their code guidelines you can see that they suggest not to mock types you don't own. You should try to refactor your code so hat the client gets abstracted.

Also you're mocking a map... Why are you mocking it? Why not just create one?